# Qt: Multi Array (from JSON); get to specific child

Tags: json, qt, qt5

I have the following json
(from Google Distance API)

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Hannover, Deutschland" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Wolfsburg, Deutschland" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "88,8 km",
                  "value" : 88790
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "58 Minuten",
                  "value" : 3473
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

And like to get the `distance` values ('text' and 'value')

When I iterate that QJsonArray like that:

```
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(bts);
    QJsonObject jsonObject = document.object();
    QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["rows"].toArray();
    foreach (const QJsonValue & value, jsonArray) {
        QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
        foreach (const QJsonValue & v, obj["elements"].toArray()) {
            QJsonObject obj2 = v.toObject();
            qDebug() << obj2["distance"];
            //returns [1]
            qDebug() << obj2["distance"].toArray();
            //returns [2]
        }
    }
```

I should be able to get the values.
However, instead I get this:

[1] =

```
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"text":"88,8 km","value":88790}) )
```

[2] =

```
QJsonArray()
```

which seems to be empty.

I dont know why that is. Because I do it just like that when getting to the "elements" array from that Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About [1]: 
obj2["distance"] is an object, not array, with fields "text" and "value", and you should do one more job:

```
QJsonObject obj2 = v.toObject();
QJsonObject finalObject = obj2["distance"].toObject();
QString text = finalObject["text"].toString();
int value = finalObject["value"].toInt();
```

or something like this.
[{}, {}, {}] - an array of objects
{"a":{}, "b":{},"c":{}} - object which contains 3 objects.

Comment: `.tostring();` should be `toString();` otherwise its working. Thanks!